# php cannot find class in same namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

I just cannot figure out the reason my phpunit test is not finding a class in the same namespace.

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LeonLombard\\OandaApi\\": ["src"]
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LeonLombard\\OandaApi\\": ["tests"]
    }
},
```

**src/OandaApi.php**

```
<?php namespace LeonLombard\OandaApi;

class OandaApi
{
}
```

**tests/OandaApiTest.php**

```
<?php namespace LeonLombard\OandaApi;

class OandaApiTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testGetAnInstrumentListWithDefaultOptions()
    {
        $oandaApi = new OandaApi();
    }
}
```

**tests/phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit
    bootsrap="../vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="All Tests">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

This is the error I am getting when I run `phpunit --config tests/phpunit.xml`:

Fatal error: Class 'LeonLombard\OandaApi\OandaApi' not found in /Users/leonlombard/Sites/oanda-api/tests/OandaApiTest.php on line 7

Any ideas would be appreciated. I have seen other posts with a similar setup and cannot see why theirs will work and not mine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please add ***/*** with ***src/*** and ***tests/*** directory in psr-04 of ***composer.json***

In composer.json

> ***Before***

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LeonLombard\\OandaApi\\": ["src"]
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LeonLombard\\OandaApi\\": ["tests"]
    }
},
```

> ***After***

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LeonLombard\\OandaApi\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LeonLombard\\OandaApi\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

I think its work for you.
And below is link please visit that.it helpful for you.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

> ***Thank you.***

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I did try that and it did not work. Read that link too to make sure I did not miss something in my understanding of PSR-4.

Comment: I deleted all the code and started step for step from the beginning and now it is working. Not sure what I missed but can confirm Brijesh suggestion is good.